# Tools to analyse CPU cache performance for Java applications?

Tags: java, performance, metrics, cpu-cache

I've no preference as regards OS; any tool will be fine so long as it allows me to measure cache performance on Core 2 and i7 architectures.

Comment: This is hard enough to do in a lower-level language like C and C++. Expect it to be even more tricky to do it through the JVM, JIT, and garbage collector.

Comment: Some specialised JVM is probably your only choice. Although surely those who develop stuff like Hotspot must have some tools to measure cache performance, they can't just stand there guessing :)

Comment: Looks like an opportunity for a guru somewhere to make some serious profit... considering Java's popularity in the enterprise application market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the only tool that does this at present is Intel VTune Performance Analyzer. It's not horrifically expensive, but it doesn't come cheap, either.

[This article](http://software.intel.com/en-us/system/files/article/149015/how-to-spice-up-java-with-the-vtune.pdf) by Intel outlines processes to improve Java app performance using this tool.

Comment: Updated link: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-spice-up-java-with-the-vtunetm-performance-analyzer-1

Answer (score 2):

This team have a product http://www.jclarity.com/ which is new but use the CPU performance counters to extract cache hit/miss information and other low level stuff.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I did upvote, but took that off; the problem is I see no availability for that product. Given the fact that they only sell it to selected clients in the financial services sector.

Comment: I don't know of any free products. Vtune from Intel used to support Java, but afaik doesn't any more.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that would be enough for you, but I used several times **JVisualVM** (included in the JDKs, at least the Sun one) as a profiling tool and I was pretty happy with it.

To find it, go to: `JAVA_HOME/bin/jvisualvm(.exe)`

Comment: It's a nice looking tool, and I will probably use it, but not for this issue. It does not address CPU cache.